# Is there a way to convert LoadRunner scripts to JMeter, apart from Blazemeter?

Tags: java, jmeter, jmeter-plugins, loadrunner

I have a couple of LR scripts and I would like to have them converted to Jmeter scripts. 
I cannot use the "JMeter proxy" method because there is some coding involved. I tried using Blazemeter but the conversion percentage is 67% and I couldnt find any .jmx file in the converted folder.
I am currently looking for alternatives; does anyone knows how to get this job done? I have been looking for quite sometime and I couldnt find an answer.

Thanks,
Mishal

Comment: Why don't you just rebuild the scripts from scratch in the next major release?

Comment: We at LR would love to hear why you need an alternative to LR. Best way is to email us through the feedback link in VuGen help menu.

Comment: @JamesPulley we are working parallel on both ways, since we have got a lot of scripts to be converted; it would be really helpful if there is a way to convert LR scripts to JMeter compatible scripts.

Comment: @Buzzy LR is a great tool but we are migrating to JMeter since we have had faced a lot of issues with Performance Center.

Comment: As performance scripts from all tools are perishable components (limited life) due to the changes in conversation between client and server, the natural point to convert is at the point of rework.   Keep in mind, you can run Jmeter scripts in the latest versions of LR, but the inverse of running LR scripts in other tools is not necessarily true.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try those:

- https://bitbucket.org/watchmouse/loadrunner
- https://github.com/kycan/loadrunner2jmeter-lr2jm